# How do i verify user in database in google appengine app ( can anyone recommend the best way to do user authentication for google appengine app)?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have following code in `models.py` i can sort database by only key but not by string ?

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Roles(ndb.Model):
name = ndb.StringProperty()
owner = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now_add = True)
class RESTMeta:
    user_owner_property = 'owner'
    include_output_properties = ['name']

class Users(ndb.Model):
name = ndb.StringProperty()
email = ndb.StringProperty()
password = ndb.StringProperty()
roles = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Roles')
owner = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now_add = True)
class RESTMeta:
    user_owner_property = 'owner'
    include_output_properties = ['name']
```

And the following in `api.py`

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
RESTHandler(
  '/api/roles', # The base URL for this model's endpoints
  models.Roles, # The model to wrap
  permissions={
    'GET': PERMISSION_ANYONE,
    'POST': PERMISSION_ANYONE,
    'PUT': PERMISSION_OWNER_USER,
    'DELETE': PERMISSION_ADMIN
  },
  # Will be called for every PUT, right before the model is saved (also supports callbacks for GET/POST/DELETE)
  put_callback=lambda model, data: model
),
RESTHandler(
  '/api/users', # The base URL for this model's endpoints
  models.Users, # The model to wrap
  permissions={
    'GET': PERMISSION_ANYONE,
    'POST': PERMISSION_ANYONE,
    'PUT': PERMISSION_OWNER_USER,
    'DELETE': PERMISSION_ADMIN
  },
  # Will be called for every PUT, right before the model is saved (also supports callbacks for GET/POST/DELETE)
  put_callback=lambda model, data: model
)],debug=True, config = config)
```

I can successfully `get` by key in `api\users?q=roles=key('key')`

How do i get specific user by **String** `api\users?q=email=String('String')`

**The Question is how do I do user auth for google appengine app**

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking so many questions in one.

To get user by email, simply do this:

```
users = Users.query(Users.email=='query_email').fetch(1)
#note fetch() always returns a list
if users:
    user_exists = True
else:
    user_exists = False
```

Please note, you may need to [update your datastore index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#creating_indexes_using_the_development_server) to support that query. The easiest way to do it is to first run the code in your local development server, and the index will be automatically updated for you.

To answer your second questions, for user authentication I would recommend [Django's in-built User Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/). Please note that you can always run vanilla [django on appengine with a Flexible VM](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) using [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) instead of the Datastore.

Alternatively, you could use the [Appengine Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/), though your users would need to have Google Accounts.